# Survey Remote Work

Tags: discussion, survey

The always-interesting Survey results are published, and the section about *remote work* got me wondering whether respondents consider "on-call" time to be remote work, and also how prevalent is the practice of keeping developers on-call.

Joining the software development industry out of college some years ago I was shocked to learn that I would be required to carry a pager periodically (on a rotation) in order to provide 24/7 support.

Is this normal? Do developers at Amazon/Apple/Facebook/Google/Microsoft etc. carry pagers? Is this a factor developers consider when applying for jobs? I know I certainly will at future interviews. Would it be worth adding such questions to the Survey next year?

Comment: Its not normal.  Having worked or contracted briefly at almost every company on your list, only Amazon made people carry pagers (these days I'm sure its just cellphones, but let's ignore that minor difference).  And they had HEAVY attrition over the issue.

What's more common is a 1 off emergency getting you a call.  That definitely happens, at any company who's software is network based.

Answer (score 1):

If they continue with tradition, there will be a post asking what questions should be on next year's survey soon. I would vote for questions asking about on call work.

> Is this normal?

I started to write an answer for this but this question isn't really about Stack Overflow. It *might* be on topic for The Workplace but I've never actually asked a question there. I've answered a few but I still don't have a firm handle on what's considered off topic so I'd check their [help](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) first.